# WebSphere mq lost message after amqsput/amqsget

Tags: shell, ibm-mq

I use MQSC for WebSphere MQ in Linux. And I created queue manager with local queue. When I try send several messages to this queue by 'amqsput'  and get by 'amqsget'  I sometimes lose my first message. Why?

Comment: Can you tell us how you identified first message is lost?

Comment: thank for question. it was just another IBM MQ lag